# Teamcity build is not running

Tags: git, build, teamcity

I am trying to run a build in teamcity. which will run some particular commands using SSH EXEC build configration.

I already run some builds with same SSH EXEC build configuration but recently i had a new build i had to run some commands in one particular server. but i am getting the error "no compatible agents for this build". Although i have compatible agents to the particular build but teamcity is not allowing to run it.

[image: This is the below pic which was showing the cause]

Can any one please find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like, these agents are restricted to running pre-defined set of build configurations.

Please, navigate to agent's page (e.g., by clicking agent's name on compatibility tab) and check "Compatible Configurations" tab, look for `Current run configuration policy` field

Comment: Thanks a lot now i configured into run assigned build configuration